# Do all languages have the subordinate clause next to the conjunction?

Tags: list-of-languages, conjunctions, subordination, complex-sentences, svo

There are example languages for almost all the possible orderings of subject, verb and object in a simple sentence, with the order of frequency being:
SOV > SVO > VSO > VOS > OVS > OSV.

My question is analogously about the possible orderings of a main clause, conjunction and subordinate clause in a complex sentence (which I'll abbreviate to M,C,S).

In English we seem to allow two orderings, MCS or CSM, as in the following examples:

- "I got good grades because I worked hard" (MCS)
- "Because I worked hard, I got good grades" (CSM)

Are there languages for all the possible orderings of main clause, conjunction and subordinate clause like there are for subject, verb and object?

In particular are there any languages allowing orders where subordinate clause is separated from the conjunction (analogous to the way in the VSO ordering the object is separated from the verb)?

Comment: Without having any particular examples in mind, I feel almost confident that Latin (particularly poetic Latin) could separate the subordinator from the rest of the subordinate clause if it wanted to, since its word order was so extremely free as to allow virtually _any_ order at all. “Grades worked good got hard I because I” would likely be perfectly allowable in Latin (using emphatic pronouns; normally the _I_’s wouldn’t be there, of course), weaving main and subordinate clause in and out of each other.

Comment: A few points about your syntax: "because" is not a conjunction but a preposition, so "because I worked hard" is a prep phrase, not a clause. The matrix (main) clause is not just "I got good grades" but the whole "I got good grades because I worked hard", in which the PP is in adjunct function. In your second example, the PP adjunct is fronted, but it is still part of the matrix (main) clause. Back to basics, Rachel!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm doubtful that Latin permits that degree of scrambling -- even highly "free word order" languages like Latin and Ancient Greek tend to keep clauses largely separate (because case marking doesn't help much when you don't know which clause a word belongs in). The main exception I can think of is topic fronting, where the topic noun of a subordinate clause appears immediately before the subordinator.

Comment: @BillJ That's a strange analysis. *Because of* is a compound preposition, but *because* is a conjunction. Are you saying that *I worked hard* is a noun phrase?

Comment: @BillJ That’s true of _English_, but not necessarily of other languages.

Comment: @TKR In normal, spoken Latin, obviously, you’d never see that kind of spaghetti syntax – but in poetry, the freedom of Latin word order seems almost unbounded to me. At least I can recall many instances of frustration from my student days at clauses that defied translation (until I was given the answer) because words didn’t appear in the clauses where they belonged. Logic connections between elements (if you could find them) were much more important than syntactic position in determining what went with what.